# Who defined the currently known performance testing metrics?

Tags: performance, testing, performance-testing, metrics

Currently I am doing a research work about performance testing. I have found a lot of websites, where the following metrics are listed as the most important system metrics:

- speed
- scalability
- stability
- reliability.

I would like to 'cite'/'reference' this list properly, but nobody wrote where it comes from and I wouldn't want to cite Wikipedia in my paper.
I've been wondering whether someone defined this in his work or common usage defined this list.
Does someone have more information about this topic?